# What type of nails should I use for the walls of my treehouse?

Tags: framing

The context is a treehouse which may get significant wind forces on it on occasion.  This is for framing the walls in particular. I have the platform handled already with some TABs / GLs and other specialty hardware - lots of watching videos from Treehouses.com, Nelson Treehouse, and others.

I'm thinking of going with screw shank nails for increased withdrawal strength of everything being held together, but didn't know if there is a reason that I should not do so and that smooth shank is actually preferred (such as because allowing some withdrawal is beneficial if that's even a thing).  I have been very impressed (and frustrated) with the holding power of screw shank nails when trying to break apart a wood pallet, so I like the idea of them.

I originally was planning to use screws for this but read that they are less ductile and not good where shear loads may be involved.  Another option is the Simpson Strong-Tie framing screws which appear to be rated as superior to nails in shear (e.g. model SDWS16300) and plus have the withdrawal strength benefits.  Nothing is going to be loaded from a withdrawal standpoint (other than indirectly from shear), but just thinking of stuff not getting creaky or loose over time.

Any overall recommendations in terms of what is proper to use here would be appreciated - I've done quite a bit of reading on this but have never framed a structure before.

Comment: Sanity check: Are you asking about building the house, or about affixing the platform to the tree? If the latter, I'd websearch for how to do so with minimum damage/risk to the tree. I know there are kits specifically designed and sold for that purpose; a homebrew is certainly possible but looking at those might help guide that design. Also, the are roughly umpteen thousand books and articles on building tree houses of varying levels of sophistication; investing some time on reading those would seem worthwhile.  Though kids have been throwing these together forever, and mostly survived...

Comment: @keshlam Good point of clarification - this is for framing the walls in particular.  I have the platform handled already with some TABs / GLs and other specialty hardware - lots of watching videos from Treehouses.com, Nelson Treehouse, and others.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter. Here's why.

- The movement in the walls (the stud-to-plate connections) should be  miniscule. If your structure is swaying that much you have other issues, mostly involving a lack of diagonal bracing.
- The wood at those locations will give (deform) enough to accommodate such movement, assuming SPF lumber.
- Nearly all force at those connections is in shear. You will not see good quality screws shear off in this use case. For some peace of mind, use *three* for each stud.
- The sheathing fasteners provide the connective force on the vertical axis, and they're also acting almost entirely in shear.

I would use screws for everything (3" for the framing, 2" for the sheathing). If you'd rather not, ring-shank nails give a bit of extra hold, but they're not going to save you from a catastrophic failure if you have so much movement that you're relying on them. Your overall structure needs to be sound.

I suggest screws because there is *some* movement in a tree--more than with a ground-based structure--and because they're nice to work with. They allow you to assemble components in awkward locations without smacking things around. They also allow easy error correction and on-the-fly design changes.

I consider any deck-type screw from reputable manufacturers to be adequate. There's no need for "rated" screws here. If we were discussing the tree connections I'd say different.

Screw shank nails don't offer much, in my experience. They'd work free in a similar manner to smooth nails, only they'd do a little twirl on the way out. Most wood pallets are built with hardwood (red oak), which explains the apparent hold of screw-shank nails.

Comment: Thanks - this makes sense, though as a follow-up question, if nearly all force is in shear, why not recommend to use nails and not screws to save time and money?  Btw, in the reading I've done, there are a lot of people raising the flag with regards to screws being okay for framing unless specifically-rated screws for that, though I assume that's what you're referring to by "good quality screws" - mainly mentioning for if others come across this.  It also may not be to code if using other types of screws.

Comment: See my updates.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of any standards for constructing a tree house. Perhaps there is.
So my answer is more of an opinion. You didn't indicate the size of the structure, but I believe you were asking only about preference of nails or screws.
I would use the Simpson screws and any metal ties that would help anchor the base or platform to the tree. Any other members I would anchor together with ring shank nails.

Comment: Why do you prefer ring shank over screw shank? Thanks

Comment: My personal experience with deck construction. I found the ring shank held PT wood better than screw shank. No extensive testing from any agency. Just my opinion...and on this forum, opinions are taboo.

Comment: Opinions are not taboo, assuming they're based on experience (which you share) and aren't product (brand) recommendations. You've already offered opinion in your answer, so your comment should be included to support it.